# How do I repair my lawn this late in the year?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

It's mid-November and we just had our driveway expanded.  Now the lawn in the region is absolutely thrashed.  Re-reading my contract with the driveway crew, they were very clear that the landscaping would be my responsibility.

I'm a total novice at lawn care.  How do I repair a lawn?  Is there anything urgent I should do before the freezing weather comes?

photo of my lawn:

[image]

There are [more photos in my imgur album)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLlWM.jpg) with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Level out the area with new soil or a strong garden tiller.

Fall is one of the best times to plant cool season grasses, I don't see palm trees so I am going to guess you have cool season turf grass.

Answer (score 1):

Given the state the area's in, it seems laying sod (turf) would be the best option, although you don't say what type of grass you originally had. If the weather's not freezing yet, you could at least start the preparation involved, which is basically digging over to remove any lumps of debris and areas where maybe the workmen walked or carried stuff so they're not compacted. Then rake level (not flat, I can see you have a slope there) so that the area is smooth and ready to take sods. I don't know where you are - were it the UK, specially in the south or west, I'd say lay turf now, but depending on your climate, it may be wiser to wait till Spring to actually lay it.